# NearbBy API notification to paired bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-notifications, google-nearby

Is it possible to send notification from an adnroid app to android OS of  another paired bluetooth device?
Or any other way to send to close device without sharing common network?

Perhaps NearbBy API or other android API tools?

Just a reasonable confirmation or deny of the question and perhaps a link on the matter would be very helpful, thank you.
I don't ask for code solution unless you're willing to provide some which would be very helpful and generous of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in the Nearby Connections API which allows nearby Android phones to communicate with each other. It requires your app to be on both phones, but it doesn't require an internet connection nor a common network.

https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/overview

Comment: Thank you Ryan very helpful.